# React Firebase Infinite Scroller Crashes / Won't print

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, infinite-scroll

So I have basically tried to troubleshoot this problem for hours now, without finding a solution to it. You see, I am currently using Firebase for my database, and I want to fetch new data using the react-infinite-scroller.

I have a Firebase database that contains 'Projects', which holds numerous child directory (unique keys) that consists of a title, content and of course a timestamp. I want to be able to use the infinite scroller to display Firebase data automatically that is fetched from my database.

I do currently have four projects that is being displayed on my website as a default, but upon scroll, I am therefore in need of loading new posts from the last/newest timestamp that is being saved in state as 'latestTimestamp' from my default load. So, I figured I am in need of constantly tracking and updating the 'latestTimestamp' in order to dispay new data correctly. And, I have tried to do this by using '.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(this.state.latestTimestamp).limitToLast(4)' without any luck.

The weird thing is that when I created the function that is being called for each load, it sometimes gets called numerous times on first page load, and sometimes it just keeps calling an infinite amount of times.

This is my code so far:

(infiniteProjects is of const { infiniteProjects } = this.state.

```
<InfiniteScroll
   pageStart={0}
   loadMore={this.loadInfinitePosts}
   hasMore={true || false}
   loader={<div className="loader">Loading ...</div>}
   useWindow={true}>
   {infiniteProjects.map((project) => {
       return(
           <div class="col-12 mb-4">
           <h3 class="project-title">{project.title}</h3>
           <p class="project-description">{project.text}</p>
           </div>
  )})}
</InfiniteScroll>
```

And here is the loadInfinitePosts:

```
loadInfinitePosts(timestamp){
    const allInfiniteProjects = [];
    var count = 0;
    databaseProjects.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(this.state.lastInfiniteTimestamp - 10).limitToLast(3).once('value', (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            count += 1;
            allInfiniteProjects.push({
                text: childSnapshot.val().text,
                timestamp: childSnapshot.val().timestamp,
                title: childSnapshot.val().title,
            });
            if(count == 1){
              console.log(childSnapshot.val().timestamp);
              this.setState(() => {
                return {
                lastInfiniteTimestamp: childSnapshot.val().timestamp
                }
            });
            }
            if(count == 3){
                allInfiniteProjects.reverse();
                this.setState(() => {
                    return {
                    infiniteProjects: allInfiniteProjects
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    });
}
```

So basically I have a really hard time displaying new posts from a specific time stamp, 4 at a time, while also keeping track of the 'latest' timestamp, which sould be used repeatedly to avoid fetching invalid posts in incorrect date order. I can't get my head around how this would work, so this is just a result of hours of trying back and forth.

Could someone please help me solve this problem? It would be of great appreciation!

Comment: Help would be greatly appreciated!